# How to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar

Tags: scrollbar

Check out my site http://hiox.org . How to get rid of horizontal scroll bar?

Answer (score 2):

Well, i did not see the horizontal scroll bar on that site. This is most likely because of resolution. Use this css style however.

```
scroll-x:hidden;
```

Comment: Hi,

I have tried overflow-x:hidden.But If i add this I can't able to view google ads in my site in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @rekhasathvika: Make sure that you have given appropriate width to your boxes/columns. Check/adjust the `width` for them.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a wider monitor (I see no horizontal scroll bars)?

Actually Sarfraz's suggestion is good, but something secondary to bear in mind is the wide range of users on your site (some using 1024x768, and still others using 1920x1200) and how to give equal usability to as many as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you could reduce the width of a few columns? "Title" and "By" look like they could be a bit smaller... then it won't force the table to be wider than neccessary, thus removing your horizontal scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Rekha, I was having the same issues with a page I was working on.

It could be that one or more of your elements widths/margins/padding/border are too wide, creating a invisible extra space in the browser.

A fix that may work is setting the `html` and `body` `padding/margin` to 0 and then changing other elements `margin` to 0 (i.e. change a header section that spans 100% of the width of the browser, change `margin` to 0).

Try looking at your page with the Firefox add-on, "Firebug" (link http://getfirebug.com/downloads), to see if there is an element's padding/margin is acting unexpectedly.

Comment: Okay so I think I forgot to mention: make your `HTML` and `BODY` selectors `width` and `height` 100% as well.